# Opamp buffer output sine wave, is it normal?

Tags: operational-amplifier, sine, single-supply-op-amp

I'm using this opamp - [GS8331/32](https://datasheet.lcsc.com/szlcsc/1810211711_Gainsil-GS8331-TR_C157712.pdf) to buffer voltage reference to ADC. Here my oscilloscope measure input and output of opamp:

[image: input]

[image]

Why ouput is sine wave? Is it normal or because of my opamp? Any way to fix this?

Here my chematic:

[image: schematic]

Thanks

Comment: How about a photograph (a sharp, well-focussed picture, please - don't waste our time with blurry stuff) of your circuit? You appear to have either significant noise pickup and/or no decoupling cap on the op amp, causing it to oscillate.

Comment: Please show your circuit so we can help.  You can use the built in circuit editor to show us a schematic of your setup.

Comment: You also need to provide a schematic diagram. Did you read the section "**Capacitive Load Tolerance**" in the datasheet? Also, this is a chopper-stabilized amplifier, and you may be seeing some effects from the chopping.

Comment: @all sorry, my mistake, I updated my question

Comment: Pls put in your design spec for output Vdc tolerance and noise Vpp and load current.  The way you C couple input to output guarantees it will be unstable